# Change homepage content if user is logged in - BuddyPress

Tags: php, login, buddypress, homepage

I'm creating a Social Network using BuddyPress, a good theme for BuddyPress itself and some plugins included with the theme that help me so much in this thing.

I'm trying to do one thing: when the user goes to **website.com**, he'll se the website informations, so like "subscribe, this is a good place" etc.
But when the user is logged in, I would that in the homepage should appear, instead of the classic homepage, the BuddyPress activity!

How could this be possible?
Can I do that?

Is like the thing that does Facebook and so many websites: if your not logged in, you can register and login, if you are logged in, you can see your Facebook home: everything ever in facebook.com

And I want to do the same on my website!

Thanks to everyone for any help!

Comment: In a nutshell: Make use of a custom front page template - `front-page.php` - and [`is_user_logged_in()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_user_logged_in) to show different content.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Is there any way to do something like this with Visual Composer?

It was shipped with my theme.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know anything about visual composer.

Answer (score 1):

I just wrote some code to do something a bit different, but it should work for what you're trying to do. It's hooked in at the `wp` hook, which will prevent redirect loop errors. This will go in either a functions.php file or your own custom plugin (recommended).

```
    add_action('wp','restrictEnterSite');

    function restrictEnterSite(){
    // Make a template of the splash page you'd like to display if user is not logged in
    $homeURL = home_url('/splash-template.php');

    //validate
    if ( $homeURL !== $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] && !is_user_logged_in() ) {

      wp_redirect($homeURL);
        exit;



    }
}
```

Give this a shot!

Comment: Thank you! This is really great!
I tried it, and I saw that it could be possible, and it's good. But I see that is not so much 'fast' as project!

What I mean is: I need to finish the job in some hours or so; then I thought to use Visual Composer to finish things quicker!

And the other problem is that I don't know how could I implement the BuddyPress Activity in this way...
Because the page should be set via BuddyPress settings...
So it's hard now...

I was thinking to have the homepage as normal, and the page /activity; if the user is logged in, when he goes to the homepage he gets [...]

Comment: [...] redirected to /activity; if the user is not logged in, he'll remain in homepage!

What do you think? How could I achieve this?

Anyway thank you really so much for your code, I'll keep it safe, dehe.

Comment: Ok, this is a quick and dirty approach. Take the code I gave you up there, and make it point to that template. Take a test page somewhere, and make the page how you want it to look. Then take that shortcode, and put it into here:

add_action('genesis_entry_content','myShortCode')
function myShortCode() {

echo do_shortcode('YOUR SHORTCODE HERE');

}

Then put all that into your template page. It's not best practice, but its fast.

Comment: Thank you anyway! I tried and it worked!
I close the question.

But now I have a problem with 404's redirects...
I open a new question. Thank you so much.